# Splitting Data into Different Sheets by Column Values

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a worksheet with multiple different values in Column A.  Is there a way to create a macro that takes all rows with column entry 0 and puts them in a separate sheet, all with entry 1 in another sheet and so on?  My first instinct is to create something that:

1) Sorts by the column in question

2) Uses an IF statement to check for the first location where the difference between the previous cell and the next cell is <> 0

3) Creates a new sheet, copies all the rows before the first difference <> 0 including the first cell in the calculation yielding a difference <> 0

4) Selects the new sheet and pastes the block of data in

5) Continues this process until a blank cell in a counter column DIFFERENT from the column being checked yields a blank value (this is because the column being sorted does have blank values)

Is there a better way to go about this?  If not, any help would be appreciated in constructing the above.  I will try to update this post with new code as I progress.

UPDATE:  I think this is a step in the right direction, if anyone could advise that would be great.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim myRange As Long


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
myRange = Range("G1:G" & lastrow)

For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    If myRange(i, i+1) <> 0 then
        Range("1:i").Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheet(3)
    Sheet(3).Paste
    ElseIf myRange(i , i+1) = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Can you show a sample data and your expected result? I don't know but I feel like I'm still missing something. I was thinking that filtering and pasting will do the job but I could be wrong.

Comment: @L42 I totally agree, the solution I proposed below revolves around (1) identifying the unique groups, (2) applying `.AutoFilter` for each group and (3) pasting each result to a new sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this design will get you where you're going... Consider a workbook that looks like this:

[image: 114]

The script below will find a blank cell in column 2 (customizable in the code), then operates on the data block per your spec. There are some sanity checks built in, including a count of the unique groups (Do you really want more than 25 resultant sheets? The number is customizable in the code of course), and are you expecting to operate on more than 10,000 rows? (The row check is also customizable.)

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitDataIntoSheets()

Dim SafetyCheckUniques As Long
SafetyCheckUniques = 25 '<~ more than this number of output sheets? might be a mistake...
Dim SafetyCheckBlank As Long
SafetyCheckBlank = 10000 '<~ more than this number of rows? might be a mistake...
Dim ErrorCheck As Long

Dim Data As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim LastCol As Long, BlankCol As Long, _
    GroupCol As Long, StopRow As Long, _
    HeaderRow As Long, Index As Long
Dim GroupRange As Range, DataBlock As Range, _
    Cell As Range
Dim GroupHeaderName As String
Dim Uniques As New Collection

'set references up-front
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")  '<~ assign the data-housing sheet
GroupHeaderName = "ID"                      '<~ the name of the column with our groups
BlankCol = 2                                '<~ the column where our blank "stop" row is
GroupCol = 1                                '<~ the column containing the groups
HeaderRow = 1                               '<~ the row that has our headers
LastCol = FindLastCol(Data)
StopRow = FindFirstBlankInCol(BlankCol, HeaderRow, Data)

'sanity check: if the first blank is more than our safety number,
'              we might have entered the wrong BlankCol
ErrorCheck = 0
If StopRow > SafetyCheckBlank Then
    ErrorCheck = MsgBox("Dang! The first blank row in column " & _
                        BlankCol & " is more than " & SafetyCheckBlank & _
                        " rows down... Are you sure you want to run this" & _
                        " script?", vbYesNo, "That's a lot of rows!")
    If ErrorCheck = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If

'identify how many groups we have
With Data
    Set GroupRange = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow, GroupCol), .Cells(StopRow, GroupCol))
    GroupRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    For Each Cell In GroupRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Cell.Value <> GroupHeaderName Then
            Uniques.Add (Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
Call ClearAllFilters(Data)

'sanity check: if there are more than 25 unique groups, do we really want
'              more than 25 sheets? prompt user...
ErrorCheck = 0
If Uniques.Count > SafetyCheckUniques Then
    ErrorCheck = MsgBox("Whoa! You've got " & Uniques.Count & " groups in column " & _
                        GroupCol & ", which is more than " & SafetyCheckUniques & _
                        " (which is a lot of resultant sheets). Are you sure you" & _
                        " want to run this script?", vbYesNo, "That's a lot of sheets!")
    If ErrorCheck = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If

'loop through the unique collection, filtering the data block
'on each unique and copying the results to a new sheet
With Data
    Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow, GroupCol), .Cells(StopRow, LastCol))
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Index = 1 To Uniques.Count
    Call ClearAllFilters(Data)
    'make sure the sheet doesn't exist already... delete the sheet if it's found
    If DoesSheetExist(Uniques(Index)) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CStr(Uniques(Index))).Delete
    End If
    'now build the sheet and copy in the data
    Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Target.Name = Uniques(Index)
    DataBlock.AutoFilter Field:=GroupCol, Criteria1:=Uniques(Index)
    DataBlock.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Target.Cells(1, 1)
Next Index
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Call ClearAllFilters(Data)

End Sub


'INPUT: a worksheet name (string)
'RETURN: true or false depending on whether or not the sheet is found in this workbook
'SPECIAL CASE: none
Public Function DoesSheetExist(dseSheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim obj As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    'if there is an error, sheet doesn't exist
    Set obj = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dseSheetName)
    If Err = 0 Then
        DoesSheetExist = True
    Else
        DoesSheetExist = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

'INPUT: a column number (long) to examine, the header row we should start in (long)
'       and the worksheet that both exist in
'RETURN: the row number of the first blank
'SPECIAL CASE: return 0 if column number is <= zero,
'return 0 if the header row is <= zero,
'return 0 if sheet doesn't exist
Public Function FindFirstBlankInCol(ffbicColNumber As Long, ffbicHeaderRow As Long, _
    ffbicWorksheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If ffbicColNumber <= 0 Or ffbicHeaderRow <= 0 Then
        FindFirstBlankInCol = 0
    End If
    If Not DoesSheetExist(ffbicWorksheet.Name) Then
        FindFirstBlankInCol = 0
    End If
    'use xl down, will land on the last row before the blank
    With ffbicWorksheet
        FindFirstBlankInCol = .Cells(ffbicHeaderRow, ffbicColNumber).End(xlDown).Row
    End With
End Function

'INPUT: a worksheet on which to identify the last column
'RETURN: the column (as a long) of the last occupied cell on the sheet
'SPECIAL CASE: return 1 if the sheet is empty
Public Function FindLastCol(flcSheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(flcSheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        FindLastCol = flcSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        FindLastCol = 1
    End If
End Function

'INPUT: target worksheet on which to clear filters safely
'TASK: clear all filters
Sub ClearAllFilters(cafSheet As Worksheet)
    With cafSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: workbook available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55764002/114_bounty.xlsb

Comment: +1 for sanity checks! I would personally disagree with using errors to check if a sheet exists, but it's definitely a more efficient method to use.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I'll need to take a bit of time to look through this answer as well.  I appreciate the workbook!

Comment: Hope it works -- I refined the code this morning too, which now checks for sheet name conflicts (and overwrites the old sheets). The workbook at the link above has been updated, and my code above is updated too

Comment: @Dan So I may be misreading this, but is it true that if on Sheet(1) I had two columns, the first containing [A,B,C] and the second containing [1,2,3] that macro would sort by [1,2,3] and create 3 worksheets:  Sheet(2) only containing cells in the second column where the value is '1'; Sheet(3) only containing cells where the value is '2'; and Sheet(4)...'3'?  It sounds like it's copying data over when it runs into a blank cell and not when it runs into a difference between two integers in a column (e.g. if B2 = 1 and B3 = 2 the row 2 will be copied and moved).

Comment: To answer your question, yes -- what you are describing will be the output given the input. The blank cell determines the boundary of the `Range` the code will work on. In the example worksheet I provided, try making row 15 in column B blank (rather than 'nope'), then run the script and you'll see that the output as much more limited. In your post, item #5 states that a blank cell in a different column should serve as the end-point

Comment: @Dan The mistake is on my end then I think.  All I meant by that was that since the 'ID' column will list all the rows where at least one column is not blank we should do a Range("A" & Lastrow) search there to get the last nonblank row, since there will be nothing to copy / paste after that point.

Comment: If you dig into my code a bit, you'll notice I wrote a function called `FindFirstBlankInCol`, which does what I think you're asking. You can customize which column the routine uses to identify the blank by changing the `BlankCol` variable

Comment: @Dan You're right, I didn't see that.  I'm going to go ahead and award you the bounty, though I may come back to ask a few questions!

Comment: Sounds good -- I did my best to really hammer on the comments in there, so my hope is that as you walk the script down you can reasonably infer what is happening. That being said, I'll be around to answer questions haha

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  The one change I had to make for my situation was this line: `Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow, GroupCol), .Cells(StopRow, LastCol))`.  I had to change it to: `Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), .Cells(StopRow, LastCol))`.

Comment: Before that change I was not getting any data in my new tabs/sheets.

Comment: Do you know how I can copy the format as well as the values into the new sheets?

Comment: hey @dmikester1 -- try the modification spelled out here (because it's too long for a comment): https://gist.github.com/danwagnerco/770ef3ec7d0b94c9e43a3ed2cef95e99

Answer (score 1):

The code I'll post is certainly not perfect, but it will get you much closer to your goal.

First, we're going to need to know how to see if a worksheet exists and, if it doesn't, how to create it. Note that boolean types are implicitly initialized to `False`.

```
Private Function isWorksheet(wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' loop through each worksheet in this workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsName = ws.name Then
            ' we found it! return true and exit the loop
            isWorksheet = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
End Function

Private Function insertNewWorksheet(wsName As String) As Worksheet
' returns newly created worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' add worksheet after all other worksheets; simultaneously setting ws = the added worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    ' rename it
    ws.name = wsName
    ' return
    Set insertNewWorksheet = ws
End Function
```

Next, we'll need to be able to find the last row for any given worksheet, so I'll take your code snippet and turn it into a function that accepts a worksheet object.

```
Private Function lastrow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Finally, we'll pull it all together in our main routine. This loops through each cell in `myRange` (column G) creating destination sheets and sending values to the last available row in Column A (1).

```
Sub processStuff()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim c As Range 'cell
Dim destWs As Worksheet
Dim srcWs As Worksheet

' use currently active sheet as source
Set srcWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
' set my range
Set myRange = srcWs.Range("G1:G" & lastrow(srcWs))

For Each c In myRange
    Dim destWsName As String
    destWsName = "Dest_" & c.Value
    If isWorksheet(destWsName) Then
        'use that worksheet
        Set destWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(destWsName)
    Else
        'create worksheet
        Set destWs = insertNewWorksheet(destWsName)
    End If
    ' sets destination cell's value
    'destWs.Cells(lastrow(destWs) + 1, 1).Value = c.Value
    ' OP asked for entire row. Oops.
    destWs.Cells(lastrow(destWs) + 1), 1).EntireRow.Value = c.EntireRow.Value
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 this is a good design, my answer above does not account for potential sheet duplication... looks like a refactor is in order

Comment: @ckuhn203 Thanks, this looks great - I'll take a look through this today to get a feel for how it works.

Comment: I just remembered that I wrote a blog post a while back on [creating safe worksheet names](http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/dynamically-naming-excel-worksheets-the-headache-free-way/). Thought it might be of interest as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Here's some pseudo code to get you started.

```
For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    If myRange(i, 1) = 0 then
        'Omitted code to move to other sheet'
    ElseIf myRange(i , 1) = 1
        'And so on'
    End If
Next i
```

Feel free to post your attempts and we'll help you along the way.  If you'd rather just pay for it, I'd be happy to send you a quote. :)

Google will provide a ton of tutorials in VBA, if you need more on the basics.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this a bit more carefully today and try to expand on it.  My first question is: how does counting the rows like that work?

Comment: That line simply counts the number of rows in the range "myRange".  You'll have to tell the macro what that range is first, however.  More on Ranges: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx.  More on the Rows property:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745%28v=office.15%29.aspx.  More one the Count property:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193349%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: It's obvious now that you say it, I had the idea in my head that you knew of a way to tell Excel to check an arbitrary range that would always give the last filled cell.  I had no idea how Excel would know which was the 'most filled' and with good reason I guess!  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, the Range.CurrentRegion is analogous to typing Ctrl + a on the keyboard, if you want to get all adjacent cells with data.  For that, you would add ` Set myRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion`