# Create new Sheet for each cell in Range and rename using its value

Tags: vba, excel, rename

I couldn't find any topic in this forum or google which helps me so I hope anyone will be able to help me here.

Here I go:

I already created this macro:

```
Sheets("Presentation PP").Select
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Presentation PP").Range("C3")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets("Presentation PP").Copy After:=Sheets(1) 'copies worksheet and creates a new one
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

So now this macro is creating for every cell in my range a copy of my sheet and renames just the last one with the value in my last cell. I need all sheets renamed by the value.

I guess I missed a sub routine. Hope someone knows how to fix that.

Comment: There are a couple of subroutines I wrote to do that in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23790033/3198973)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub MainMoD()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Presentation PP")

    For Each cell In ws.Range("C3:C" & ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        ws.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = cell.Value
    Next

End Sub
```